# How to get customer id by phone number in magento 2.4 login api

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I am new in magento api developement for mobile app. I have to write API code for login. This application login has no password and login by mobile phone otp verification.
During my coding, I can access customer id by email.

```
     $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
     $customer->loadByEmail($email);
     $customerId = $customer->getId();
```

But I need to access this **customer id by phone number**,instead of this.
What will be the code for 'loadbyphone'?

Comment: Maybe something like this: `$customer->load($phoneNumber, 'phone_number_attribute')`

Answer (score 0):

We can do it following way. But make sure Phone number is unique.

```
$customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
$customer->load($telephone_number,'telephone_number');
$customer->getData();
```